# Find all homomorphisms $A_4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

**Task:**

Find all homomorphisms $A_4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

$ A_4 = \{e; (12)(34); (13)(24); (14)(23); (123); (132); (124); (142); 
(134); (143); (234); (243) \} $

$\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\} $

**My solution:**

We take two elements of order 3 from $A_4$ and check the order of their multiplication:
$$(1 2 3) (1 2 4) = (1 3) (2 4)$$
It means that from two elements of order 3, we can got an element of order 2

In $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ we cannot do this, in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ we get either an element of order 0 or an element of order 3 from two elements of order 3, because we have only two elements of order 3: 2 and 4.

2 + 4 = 4 + 2 = 0 (order 0)

2 + 2 = 4 (order 3)

4 + 4 = 2 (order 3)

And with homomorphism, the order of the image must divide the order of the original element,  so we cannot transfer an element of order 3 to an element of order 2. Therefore, we have only one trivial homomorphism

Am I right or not? thanks for all tips

Comment: $(123)(124)$ has order 2, but its image doesn't have to.

Comment: There is no order zero element of a group. The order of an element $g$ is the smallest *positive* integer $n$ such that $g^n=e$.

Comment: @Shaun, hmm, then it turns out there should be an order of $\infty$

Comment: In a *finite* group!?  No, the order of the identity is $1$.

Comment: @Arthur, $(123)$ сan go to element with order of 1 or 3. It is 2 or 4 in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. $(123)(124) = (13)(24)$ - order of 2. if we add 2 elements of order 3 to Z6, we will not get an element of order 2. Then (13)(24) go to 0. The rest of the elements will be engaged in similar reasoning and we will get a trivial homomorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_4=\langle(123),(124)\rangle$ and both $(123)$ and $(124)$ have order $3$; now let $f:A_4\to\Bbb{Z}_6$ be an homomorphism, we know that given a set of generators an homomorphism is uniquely determined by the images of the generators; since $o(f(g))|o(g)$ and elements in $\Bbb{Z}_6$ have either order $1, 2, 3, 6$ you can send $(123)$ and $(124)$ either in $[0]$, $[2]$ or $[4]$. Now consider that $(123)^3=(124)^3=1$ and $\left((123)(124)\right)^2=\left((13)(24)\right)^2=1$; therefore we must send $(123)$ in $[2]$ and $(124)$ in $[4]$ or vice versa, or both of them in $[0]$ so the possible homomorphisms are 3 in total.